# Can't create a collection in MongoDB datatbase

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mlab

Using this code to create a collection on MongoDB database hosted on mlab. But somehow it does not seems to be working. Is there something I am missing in this code? .save() function does not seem to be firing at all. Can it be due to my schema?

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var Schema= mongoose.Schema;

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//connect to mongo db database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://blaa:blaa@ds127132.mlab.com:27132/vendor');


//vendor schema
var vendorSchema= new Schema({
  name:String,
  image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
  vendortype:String,
  location: {
   type: [Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
   index: '2d'      // create the geospatial index
  },
  contactinfo:String,
  description:String
});

//creating a  model for mongoDB database
var Vendor= mongoose.model('Vendor',vendorSchema);

//just putting a sample record data
var imgPath = 'public/images/background.jpg';
var one = Vendor({
name: 'Justin Motor Works',
vendortype: 'Automobile',
contactinfo:'6764563839',
location: {
  type:[23.600800037384033,46.76758746952729]
},
image: {
  data: fs.readFileSync(imgPath),
  contentType: 'image/jpg'
},
description: 'Motor workshop'
}).
save(function(err){
  if(err)
  throw err;
  else {
  console.log('create record failed');
  }
});
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you starting the server so it can connect?

Comment: well, I m just starting a server and rendering a HTML file. I m looking in to the database for any newly created collection.

Comment: does this line mongoose.connect('mongodb://blaa:blaa@ds127132.mlab.com:27132/vendor');  not supposed to throw error when database is not connected. I tried the URL with mongo terminal it says its connected properly

Comment: The data you are supplying to `"location"` is incorrect and will throw an error on validation. It should be `location: [23.600800037384033,46.76758746952729]` because that is how you actually defined it in your schema, as an array of number `[Number]`. I think you are confusing the mongoose schema "type" with being an actual field name. When I correct that and remove the "express" parts this creates just fine. Also you are logging `'create record failed'` when in fact the logic would be at this point that it actually succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, I tried to create the record removing the location field as well but it still didn't work then I updated the mongoose package in my JSON file I change it to "mongoose": "4.2.6" and it worked thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.connect` is an asynchronous function, you need to put your code inside a callback or `promise.then(function(){`.

**Try this:**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://blaa:blaa@ds127132.mlab.com:27132/vendor', function(error) {
    if (error)
        //handle error
    //Your code
});
```

**Or this:**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://blaa:blaa@ds127132.mlab.com:27132/vendor').then(
  () => {
    //Your code
  },
  err => {
    //Your error handling
  }
);
```

Notice the error handling, it's important to know what caused the error for future debugging.

---

Also change the JSON structure of `location` when you are saving it as @NeilLunn said in the comments to something like this:

```
location: [23.600800037384033,46.76758746952729],
```

`type` in mongoose means actually defining the type of the key, and not a nested `type` key.